# Call internal features in MySQL Workbench plugin (python)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm writing a python plugin for MySQL Workbench. Inside my plugin, after executing some instructions, I need to execute a "Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script" (com.mysql.wb.menu.file.export), opening the related dialog to export the current Model in a sql file. If it is possible, how I can do it? I looked at the documentation but haven't find what I was looking for. The alternative would be to do it clicking on the export option by hand, but this would be really annoying in our working process. I need some explanations or example.

Thanks for your help.